# How to Create New App Bundle of Existing Android Studio Project with new Name and Package Name.

Tags: android, terminal, command

I Have an Existing Android Studio Project bundle. Now i have to create new App bundle with new App Name,Package Name and new theme color without using ide.

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

for create new package name and move to another in android app>java (right click)>New > package (create new package) and select package which you wants to move (right click)> Refactor>Move  [enter the created package name then move it]

Comment: I don't have to use any ide. We can use Command line or Terminal.

Comment: check this may be its helps you.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package